# Updating paperclip avatar in multipart simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create an edit page for the below form. The problem is that when the user browses to the edit page the brand_name and name are pre-filled, but the image upload field shows 'no file chosen' even when an avatar exists for the 'style'. Please let me know if there is some way to remedy this. Thanks!

My Edit Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @style, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :remote => true do |m| %>

    <%= m.input :brand_name, :label => 'Brand', :placeholder => 'Brand' %>    
    <%= m.input :name, :label => 'Style', :placeholder => 'Style' %>
    <%= m.input :avatar, :label => "Image" %>

    <div class="form-actions" style = "background:none">
      <%= m.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', styles_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just implemented this yesterday. Make a custom input in /app/inputs

```
class AvatarInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::FileInput
def input
out = '' # the output string we're going to build
# check if there's an uploaded file (eg: edit mode or form not saved)
if object.send("#{attribute_name}?")
  # append preview image to output
  # <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail', id: 'avatar' %>
  out << template.image_tag(object.send(attribute_name).url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail', id: 'avatar')
  end
# append file input. it will work accordingly with your simple_form wrappers
    (out << @builder.file_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)).html_safe
  end
end
```

Then you can do

```
<%= f.input :avatar, :as => :avatar %>
```

Comment: Do I need to fork the gem and add to simple_form / lib / simple_form / inputs ?

Comment: Figured out just put it in my app ... inside inputs... GREAT work.

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought that happened automatically. Thanks again!

Comment: @DVG what would i access if there is a association like post.avatar.image

Comment: `attribute_name` is a simple-form attr_reader, so I don't think you'll be able to go another level deep and do an attribute of a related object. The first thing I'd try would be to add a delegate to your Avatar object so post can call image directly as an attribute: https://gist.github.com/4208766

Answer (score 6):

This is all I needed for this to work (in haml):

```
=simple_form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f|
  =f.file_field :image
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for new/edit views from [paperclip's github page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :user, @user, :url => user_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

So maybe you should try `m.file_field` and include `:html => { :multipart => true }` as well? Though I personally prefer [Attachment-Fu](https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu).

Comment: this is about simple_form not rails standard form